# In Eureka Season 2, does Henry Deacon remember the circumstances of Kim Anderson's death?

Tags: timeline, eureka

In the Season 1 finale "One in a Lifetime" Jack Carter

> travels into the past to prevent Henry from saving Kim's life and creating an alternate timeline, thus erasing his and Henry's own future.

Upon resolving the timeline, Henry confronts Carter, knowing that he made the right decision but unable to accept it. They agree to erase their memories of the event, but Henry

> secretly destroys the memory device after erasing Carter's memory, and angrily says that he will never forget.

Early in Season 2 it's implied that Henry is still dwelling on the incident, leaving the possibility for tension between him and Carter, but they eventually resume their close friendship and the subject is never touched on again.

In later episodes does Henry still remember Carter's role and just get over it, or did something happen to change his past or memories? Was this plot thread intentionally written out of the series, or did it get resolved at some point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spoiler concerning season 2:

> The hatred and bitterness that Henry is showing in the scene you mentioned earlier is - at least that's what I'm getting from it - supposed to be directed at Beverly Barlowe.
> In later scenes, Henry's angry words "I will never forget." are shown in flashbacks, when the topic of Beverly causing Kim's death comes up.

Spoiler concerning seasons 4+5:

> In the new timeline, Henry gets to know Grace and at least at this point in time he is over the loss of Kim (Although one could argue that the bio-computer-thingy from season 3 had already given him closure).

To conclude: Nah, I don't think that something messed with Henry's past/memory. It's rather that Jack never was the real recipient of Henry's hostility. (Although the writers might have deliberately implied this in earlier scenes)